# Eclipse "Variables" window, changed value color

Tags: eclipse

I can't find how to change the background color on the "Variables" window. When a variable is changed while debugging, it highlights it with a horrible yellow background that in my zenburn style colorset doesn't allow me to see the line clearly.

Can I change that background somehow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Today I finally got fed up with this myself and looked around. In `Preferences->Run/Debug` you can set the `Changed value background color` to whatever you wish. It seems like the `Changed value color` is ignored. (In fact, if it weren't ignored, this wouldn't be a problem in the first place cause the text would be red on yellow instead of white on yellow. ;)

Comment: 2 years old, still gold :-) When I select a different entry in the variables window, that entry is marked blue, the variable name shows white (fine), but the value shows black, hard to read on blue. Happen to know where to change that?

Comment: Using the eclipse with Ac6 on STM32. When I have an array where variables have not changed in value, they are displayed as white on yellow i.e. UNREADABLE. I have to select them with a mouse to read them. Have looked through lots of preference menus but cannot find a way to turn this very very difficult to use colour scheme off.